# Compile Angular2 in Cordova with Cordova Plugins

Tags: javascript, angular, cordova, cordova-plugins

I have a Cordova app, with an angular 2 app inside it, compiling into the www folder.

structure

```
cordova
 - hooks
 - plugins
 - ng (angular app)
   - src
   - angular-cli.json
 - www
 - platforms
 etc ...
```

in the angular-cli.json I have

```
"scripts": ["../../platforms/ios/www/cordova.js","../../platforms/ios/www/cordova_plugins.js",
      "../../plugins/cordova-plugin-geolocation/www/geolocation.js",
      "../../plugins/cordova-plugin-geolocation/www/Coordinates.js",
      "../../plugins/cordova-plugin-geolocation/www/Position.js",
      "../../plugins/cordova-plugin-geolocation/www/PositionError.js"],
```

which kind of seems to bundle stuff in, its hard to tell.  While in Chrome log I get

> Could not find cordova.js script tag. Plugin loading may fail.
>
> zone.js:196 Uncaught Error: Module cordova-plugin-geolocation.Coordinates does not exist.

and a slew of

> GET errors for 'http://localhost:4200/plugins/cordova-plugin-geolocation/www/Coordinates.js' and others.

It all seems a bit tacky, and I'm not even sure yet how I can access the navigator object yet from the .ts files to get to the plugins.

Has anyone managed to solve this in a nice way?

Comment: I don't use cli, but I just added cordova.js in a script tag to index.html and it works like a charm.

Comment: You don't need to, and should not, load the plugins yourself.